# A dialog with a JList of entries or manually entering text as a separate choice

Tags: java, swing

I have a list of strings I was going to put into a JList and pass that into a choice dialog box. I also want to be able to manually enter a text string and have that be another choice you can choose. What is the simplest way to do that? I want the dialog to prompt the user for a selection of one of the strings or manually enter a value.

Can I do that with one of those prepackaged dialogs? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `List` (like `ArrayList`)? `JList` is something different.

Comment: Not with me now I'm home.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How To Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). In particular, take a look at [Using an Editable Combo Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable).

Answer (score 1):

How about a [`JComboBox` that's editable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable)?

```
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>(listOfThings);
box.setEditable(true);
```

(omit the `<String>`s if you're pre-Java 7)

This will create a `JComboBox` that holds elements of type `String`, starting with the default list of elements stored in the `listOfThings` object (a `String[]` or `Vector<String>` will work fine).

The second line sets it to be *editable*, so the user can enter a custom choice.

To display in a dialog:

```
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>(listOfThings);
box.setEditable(true);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, box); // this method blocks
System.out.println("You chose " + box.getValue());
```

Comment: You mean Java 5. Generics were introduced in Java 5.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Generics were introduced in Java 5, but `JComboBox` was only made generic in Java 7.